# Create form like "Create Article" in component (frontend part) in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, components

Anybody know how to create a form just like in "Create Article" in com_content component.
Basically i want to make a form in my component frontend part.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet will be to download a form module and embed it in the article.

Check these 2 categories to see which extension suits your needs.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms

Once you have a module, give it a custom position by typing one in instead of selecting one, then go to your article and use the following code:

```
{loadposition xxx}
```

Hope this helps.